# DataTable Reloading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I really don't understand why my code is not reloading because when I use early it works fine but now it's always throw this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=staff_rep - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#staff_rep').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
  });
});

var usid;

$(document).on('click', '.del', function() {
  usid = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
});

$('#ok_button1').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "destroy/" + usid,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#ok_button1').text('Deleting...');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // setTimeout(function() {
      //     $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
      //     $('#ok_button1').text('Ok');
      //     $('#staff_rep').DataTable().ajax.reload();
      // }, 1000);
      if (data.type == 'success') {
        $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
        $('#ok_button1').text('Ok');
        $('#staff_rep').DataTable().ajax.reload();
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: The link in the error gives you full instructions on how to debug the issue - your JSON format doesn't match what's required by DataTables. Their documentation shows you the format you need to use: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: Show us the Controller's method source code meant to handle this request. This error usually happens when your backend throws an error while handling the request. Try clearing and inspecting your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file for any backend errors.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `columns: [...]` DataTable option.